# why this happen in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have the following Statements in sql

```
 declare @date varchar(20)
 declare @query  NVARCHAR(MAX)

 set @date= '2013-1-1'
 set @query= 'print '+@date+''
 execute (@query)
```

iam getting the answer as 2011 not as 2013-1-1.. 
why this is happening. what to do to get the answer as 2013-1-1 instead of 2011 using
execute(@query) statement

Comment: It is getting subtracted.. 2013-1-1=2011

Comment: @asifsid88 it's correct. but i need to get 2013-1-1 in this way(using execute(@query))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is effectively:

```
print 2013-1-1
```

Caused by:

```
'print '+@date+''
```

If you rewrote your SQL to be:

```
print @data
```

You would get the value printed: 2013-1-1

If you updated your original query:

```
declare @date varchar(20)
declare @query  NVARCHAR(MAX)

set @date= '2013-1-1'
set @query= 'print '''+@date+''''
execute (@query)
```

This would be the same as writing:

```
print '2013-1-1'
```

Comment: i have a complex problem i simplied the problem and asked the question. i need to get 2013-1-1 using 'print '+@date+''

Comment: @user1925921 I think you should try the code provided in the answer before you comment. Another option would be to assign the value to `@date` with quotes. Like this: `set @date= '''2013-1-1'''`.

Comment: @user1925921 your query is nothing more than a bit of math when you execute it, and I'm unsure how we can help solve your complex problem since I think to most people this would be considered a rather silly question. No offense.

Answer (score 0):

u can try like this also....this will also give u the answer

declare @date varchar(20)
 declare @query  NVARCHAR(MAX)

set @date= '2013-1-1'
 set @query= 'print '''+@date+''''
 execute (@query)